# Symfony Doctrine Mongo ODM queryBuilder only returning the first document

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have this entity called `Employee` where one of the field is an `ArrayCollection` which contains another entity called `Invoice` stored as the invoice id.

Its worth mentioning here is that Employee and Invoice has many-to-many relationship. That is 1 employee document can have multiple different invoices and one invoice can have multiple different employees.

So now I want to build a query with which it will return all the employees that matches a certain invoice.

In my database, I have these two employees which have the same invoice stored as id in the array collection.

Employee collection:

```
{
  id: 'employee1',
  invoices: [
    ObjectId('invoice1')
  ]
}

{
  id: 'employee2',
  invoices: [
    ObjectId('invoice1')
  ]
}
```

Invoice collection:

```
{
  id: 'invoice1',
  employees: [
    ObjectId('employee1'),
    ObjectId('employee2')
  ]
}
```

When I run the query I only get the first employee instead of the two. Here's what I did:

```
public function findEmployeeByInvoiceQuery(Invoice $invoice) {
  $dm    = $this->getDocumentManager();
  $query = $dm->createQueryBuilder(Employee::class)->field('invoices')->in([$invoice]);
  
  return $query->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Please note that when I check the debugger I saw invoices field as `PersistenceCollection` instead of `ArrayCollection`.

Comment: How relationships are defined, and how do you iterate the result?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the SQL code for this request via $query->getQuery()->getSQL() ?

I usually join the two table (with ManyToMany relation) to have exactly what I want (from a repository) :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('employee')
->innerJoin('employee.invoices', 'inv')
->andWhere('inv.id = :invoiceId')
->setParameter('invoiceId', $invoice);
```

Source for QueryBuilder : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use query builder's `includesReferenceTo` method to deal with querying ManyToMany.

```
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder(Employee::class)->field('invoices')->includesReferenceTo($invoice);
```

Documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.3/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-reference

Offhand, why not use `$invoice->getEmployees()` as you already have it in place?